# Angles of a Tetrahedron

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polyhedra, solid-geometry, solid-angle

Consider points A, B, C and D such that ∠ACB = 30◦, ∠CBD = 26◦, ∠DBA = 51◦ and ∠DAC = 13◦. Compute all possible values of the ∠BDC.

This is a 3D-Geometry problem. So I am assuming ABCD is a tetrahedron. It is not specified which is the base of the tetrahedron.

Comment: Any face of a tetrahedron can be the "base."

Comment: Sorry, my mistake

Comment: Since each face is a triangle there are 4 triangles in this tetrahedron.  Only one angle is given for each triangle here. How can you limit the scope of this problem? Is there a relation between the angles of different faces?

Comment: Assuming ABC is the base and D is the vertex at the top do all the 3 angles BDC + BDA + ADC equal 180 degrees?

Comment: No, but we do know that $BDC + BDA + ADC \leq 360$ degrees (with equality only if you allow $D$ to be _on_ the face $ABC$, that is, a degenerate tetrahedron).

Comment: Right, I wanted to say 360, not 180.

Comment: So the 4 triangles are not related to one another except the inequality that was pointed out earlier.